# Evitar mensagem de demora de resposta

Tags: android, rest, asynctask

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que consome, via REST, um serviço de terceiros.
Em alguns casos o serviço demora a me responder e, como o aplicativo fica esperando resposta surge uma mensagem oferecendo ao usuário a opção de aguardar ou encerrar o aplicativo, tal qual como mostra a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta mensagem aparece principalmente quando uso conexão 3G para consumir o serviço.

Existe alguma forma de evitar esta mensagem ou aumentar o tempo de resposta indefinidamente?

Eu não utilizei AsyncTask. Eu tentei realizar algumas adaptações mas não obtive sucesso. Então eu gostaria de saber se, dentro destas circunstâncias, existe a possibilidade de evitar a mensagem. Se a utilização do AsyncTask for a única maneira de evitar este cenário eu apreciaria bastante a recomendação de um material (ou explicação) que seja compreensível para alguém que não possui tanta experiência com Android, como eu =)

Desde já, agradeço =)

Answer (score 0):

Me supreende você sequer conseguir consumir um serviço sem utilizar [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

De qualquer forma. As opções que você tem, que alias são as mais comuns, é utilizar [Volley](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/volley/index.html) ou [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Tem bastantes material por ai, como este:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2nwFenaWRM

e este http://www.devmedia.com.br/android-retrofit-primeiros-passos-com-a-retrofit-api/31857

Exemplo com volley:

```
    final TextView tvMeuTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.meu_textview);

    String url = "http://www.meu.server.com/meujson";

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    tvMeuTextView.setText("Resposta do servidor: " + response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // em caso de erro na requisição, trata-o aqui
                }
            });

    //Preferencialmente crie um singleton para isso
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsObjRequest);
```

Comment: Olá,  @Androiderson. Você poderia incluir uma pequena demonstração de código na sua resposta? Caso algum dia esses links fiquem indisponíves, ainda existirá código aqui de backup. Além de agregar mais valor ao stackoverflow.